# Canging coordinate system units from mm to m using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, arcgis-10.6, units

I've received a feature dataset, that has a wrong amount of digits/wrong unit as coordinates. The coordinate system is actually a variation of Gauß-Krüger, which coordinates normally look like in this example:

E 33570272.656, N 5652121.859 (in meter)

Unfortunately the feature dataset has coordinates with too many digits (millimeter instead of meter):

E 33570272656, N 5652121859 (here in millimeter!)

I've already tried changing the linear units of my coordinate system to millimeter, which had no effect. Maybe someone knows a solution for changing the coordinates to meter?

The parameters of my coordinate system look like this:
[image]

I'm using ArcGIS Basic 10.6 and I don't have any programming skills

Comment: What are the XY tolerance and resolution values?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's possible to edit a CRS to use mm as unit.

Anyway if your data are point one way would be adding X and Y field (there is a calculate geometry tool for that), exporting the data to table then dividing the X and Y field by 1000 to convert to meter.

You could then use the updated table and display the XY data.

If your data are line or polygon you may try to convert to point first then divide the coordinate and converting back to original geometry.

Comment: Yes, of course you could make a custom projected coordinate reference in units of millimeters. It's probably unwise to do so, but it's certainly possible.